Using OpenRewrite, how do I make pomXml ignore version?
The problem I am having is we have a test similar to this...
class UpgradeNonSpringDependenciesTest : RewriteTest {
    override fun defaultExecutionContext(sourceSpecs: Array<out SourceSpec<*>>): ExecutionContext {
        val ctx: ExecutionContext = InMemoryExecutionContext { t: Throwable? -> AssertionsForClassTypes.fail("Failed to parse sources or run recipe", t) }
        MavenExecutionContextView.view(ctx).setMavenSettings(MavenSettings.readMavenSettingsFromDisk(ctx))
        return ctx
    }

    @Test
    fun upgradeDependencies() = rewriteRun(
        { spec ->
            spec.recipeFromResource("/META-INF/rewrite/my.yml", "net.me.recipe.maven.UpgradeNonSpringDependencies")
        },
        pomXml(
            """
            <project>
              <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
              <groupId>com.example</groupId>
              <artifactId>example-artifact</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.me</groupId>
                  <artifactId>kafka-core</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </project>
            """.trimIndent(),
            """
            <project>
              <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
              <groupId>com.example</groupId>
              <artifactId>example-artifact</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.me</groupId>
                  <artifactId>kafka-core</artifactId>
                  <version>2.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </project>
            """.trimIndent()
        ) { spec -> spec.path("pom.xml") }
    )
}

The problem here is when we roll out a new version say 2.0.2, the test fails.
[ERROR]   UpgradeNonSpringDependenciesTest.upgradeDependencies:21 [Unexpected result in "pom.xml":
diff --git a/pom.xml b/pom.xml
index 8c9f791..0e1d1c7 100644
--- a/pom.xml
+++ b/pom.xml
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.me</groupId>
       <artifactId>kafka-core</artifactId>
-      <version>2.0.1</version>
+      <version>2.0.2</version>
     </dependency>

How do I get it to just ignore the version so I don't have to worry. Or even better, make sure that the version is greater without worrying about if it is a particular version?

You'll want to use the SourceSpec.after method, as seen here:
https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-testing-frameworks/blob/433685ea3c32f39df471a26b9b18be840d3bca77/src/test/java/org/openrewrite/java/testing/hamcrest/MigrateHamcrestToAssertJTest.java#L542-L587
        @Test
        void assertjMavenDependencyAddedWithTestScope() {
            rewriteRun(
              mavenProject("project",
                srcTestJava(java(JAVA_BEFORE, JAVA_AFTER)),
                //language=xml
                pomXml("""
                    <project>
                        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                                <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
                                <version>2.2</version>
                                <scope>test</scope>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </project>
                    """,
                  sourceSpecs -> sourceSpecs.after(after -> """
                    <project>
                        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
                                <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
                                <version>%s</version>
                                <scope>test</scope>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                                <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
                                <version>2.2</version>
                                <scope>test</scope>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </project>
                    """.formatted(Pattern.compile("<version>(3\\.2.*)</version>").matcher(requireNonNull(after)).results().findFirst().orElseThrow().group(1))))
              )
            );
        }


I did do something similar but way more complex as I made sure the versions were at least a patch ahead no matter what version either were. This was so even when there was a major upgrade it would still work without edits. Also because it was multiple deps I had to parse to hashmap to make sure I got them all
